# Change "Pulse notification light" / trackball light setting on Android (Nexus One only?)

Tags: android, settings, notifications, light, trackball

On the Nexus One (at least in 2.1-update1, and I think in 2.1), there is a setting under Sound & Display: "Pulse notification light". This doesn't seem to be present on the "2.1 with Google APIs" emulator image. I've not yet checked any other devices.

[Pulse notification light: Pulse trackball light repeatedly for new notifications http://chris.boyle.name/images/20100206-pulse-trackball.png](http://chris.boyle.name/images/20100206-pulse-trackball.png)

I want to set this programmatically without user interaction, in order to make a Locale plugin, so the device can grab my attention when I'm awake at my desk, without having it floodlighting the room when someone spams me at 4am. It's quite bright.

I didn't see it in [android.provider.Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) where many other things on this screen live, so I had a look in the platform source. There are some relevant parts in NotificationManagerService, in [enqueueNotificationWithTag](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java#l748) and [updateLightsLocked](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java#l966). That goes off into [HardwareService](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/HardwareService.java#l292) which seems well past the point of caring about user settings. I've no idea where this setting is implemented or how I might influence it.

I fully expect the answer to be "there is no API for this" (perhaps related to it being Nexus One specific), and that the best I can do is to schedule (using Locale or something else) an Intent of [ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS) to remind me to set the box manually, which would suck. I'm hoping that I've missed something, or that [a Googler is reading this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html) and can tell me that this is planned for addition to the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I'm going to die painfully for using an undocumented API (or rather, undocumented system setting name), but here is the magic line:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
        "notification_light_pulse", on ? 1 : 0);
```

Found using `sqlite3` on my own device.

Here is this solution in a convenient Locale plugin: http://chris.boyle.name/projects/ptlp

Comment: Worked fine for a bunch of devices, but returns wrong results for Samsung Galaxy S3 and Galaxy Note 2.