# Access Led light

Tags: android, android-settings

I'm trying to access `LED NOTIFICATION` in Android, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304971/disable-enable-notification-led) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211543/change-pulse-notification-light-trackball-light-setting-on-android-nexus-on) question here on Stack.
When I try to call

```
Settings.System.getInt(resolver, "notification_light_pulse")
```

the program crashes because it can't find `notification_light_pulse`.

How can I do to access the `LED NOTIFICATION` if this method fail?

Comment: This is an undocumented API that will only work on some devices, and crash on others.

Comment: You should have written this as an answer @Patrick

Answer (score 0):

This is an undocumented API that will only work on some devices, and crash on others.